# avro runtime exception not a map when return in Json format

Tags: json, avro

i have a avro schema for UKRecord, which contain a list of CMRecord(also avro schemaed):

```
{
    "namespace": "com.uhdyi.hi.avro",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "UKRecord",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "coupon",
            "type": [
                "null",
                "string"
            ],
            "default": null
        },
        {
            "name": "cm",
            "type": [
                "null",
                {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "type": "record",
                        "name": "CmRecord",
                        "fields": [
                            {
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "string",
                                "default": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string",
                                "default": ""
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "default": null
        }
    ]
}
```

in my java code, i create a UKRecord which has all fields populated correctly, eventually i need to return this object using a json based api, however it complained:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a map: {"type":"record","name":"CmRecord","namespace":"com.uhdyi.hi.avro","fields":[{"name":"id","type":"string","default":""},{"name":"name","type":"string","default":""}]}
```

the java code that write the object to json is :

```
ObjectWriter writer = ObjectMapper.writer();
if (obj != null) {
   response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.Names.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
   byte[] bytes = writer.writeValueAsBytes(obj);  <-- failed here
        ...
}
```

obj is:

```
{"coupon": "c12345", "cm": [{"id": "1", "name": "name1"}, {"id": "2", "name": "name2"}]}
```

why do i get this error? please help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Avro, but I'm guessing you should show your Java code, if only to ensure that it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using unions, Avro is uncertain how to interpret the JSON you are providing.  Here's how you can change the JSON so Avro knows it's not null

```js
{
  "coupon": { "string": "c12345" },
  "cm": { "array": [
          { "id": "1", "name": "name1" },
          { "id": "2", "name": "name2" }
        ]
  }
}
```

I know, it's really annoying how Avro chose to handle nulls.